# ODE with the term $(y')^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I read my lecture notes for $1$st order ODE, the differential parts I can see are $$y',\, yy',\, xyy',\ldots$$

In my project, I met the following ODE

$$\frac{-1}{4r}b^2(y')^2-x^2y'+2xy+(c_1+c_2x^2)=0,$$ where $$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}.$$

I does not look like linear, separable, exact ODE.

Would anyone please give me a hint that how to deal with $(y')^2$ term?

Thanks!

Comment: Try an ansatz $y = Ax^{\alpha}$. I think you'll find $\alpha = 1$. Else, if the initial conditions don't work for this guess then as the problem is fully nonlinear you're best off trying a numerical solution.

Comment: First thing that strikes me is a quadratic in $(y')$ but I think it would get real messy real quick.

Comment: It is certainly not linear. There is probably some intended trick or way of going about this problem, based on the constants which appear.

Comment: It might be an idea to write something about how the equation was derived, especially the origin and meaning of the constants (?) $b, r$ (from your original problem, I guess) and $c_1, c_2,$ which seem to appear from other sources, or is the different naming just a coincidence?